# 403 forbidden error -executing and ajax page

Tags: php, jquery, error-handling

I am having a website everything works fine.But i am getting the following error only  when i call a ajax page page from php.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access test.php
on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at salarypayroll.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

It was working fine before ,just now am facing an issue like this.what would be the problem .......?
Is it like any permission or security issue in server .......?

My function :

```
function myfunc(){
 var test = $("#test").val();  


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:   'test.php',
        data:{
            "test" : test,
             },
    success: function(data) 
             {
             /*--------My code-------*/

              }     

      });
}
```

Comment: show us how you call the ajax-page from php

Comment: Post your ajax code, also have you tried to directly access test.php from browser? Same permission page?

Answer (score 0):

change permission of test.php file

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when test.php file not exist or path to test.php file is invalid.

Check file path in ajax code.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems.

It's caused by special chars in the query string.

In your case probably by the { inside data.

You should check apache rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your host allows http URL in form posts. Some hosts deploy a mod_sec rule which prevents http:// url passed via post.