# 403 Error Persists After Changing File Permissions & Editing Htaccess File

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

Below is some background on why I am asking this [question](https://medium.com/@gordon_zhu/how-to-be-great-at-asking-questions-e37be04d0603?fbclid=IwAR3tear8b4t7olUlkKbMjOxw-iWTCUu-3Uf1HPZwofIYtdlsEfRN-TsQU2M) followed by some research I have done as of now before bringing this question forward.  I hope that I am asking the correct question. As is it often the case that we ask the wrong question because we do not fully understand the issue and therefore waste our time and those of others.

**Discovery of an issue:**

I click a button on my website that is supposed to save edits to an article.  When I do click the button,  I get the following : it turns white and nothing changes.

Below is the **code for the button in question** this button exists in the file **community/profile.php.**

```js
<button onclick="saveEditedArticle();" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block" id="edit_postbutton">Save Article</button>
```

**Initial Steps Taken To Investigate The Problem**

I opened up the chrome dev tools to see what could possibly be happening.

**1) In [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) I Get A 403 Error**

```js
10jquery.js:8630 POST https://bullbuster.net/community/controllers/article.php 403
send @ jquery.js:8630
ajax @ jquery.js:8166
saveEditedArticle @ (index):591
onclick @ (index):6451
```

**2) [I Do Some Research To See What A 403 Error Is](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/what-is-403-forbidden-error-and-how-to-fix-it)**

**3) I Use Google & Find Stack Overflow Questions On This Issue:**

[403 forbidden error -executing and ajax page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793165/403-forbidden-error-executing-and-ajax-page)

[403 Forbidden error when making an ajax Post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259792/403-forbidden-error-when-making-an-ajax-post-request)

**4) I am told a 403 Error Means That My File Has The Wrong Permissions**

I then change the permissions for : 
https://bullbuster.net/community/controllers/article.php

to **0755**  ([what this means](http://permissions-calculator.org/decode/0755/)) from **0644** ([what this means](http://permissions-calculator.org/decode/0644/))

**5) I am told it is possible that it is an issue with my *htaccess* file:**

```js
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Below is the part of the file from the ***community/controllers/article.php*** that access is being forbidden from (403) even though **this file has 0755 permissions**

```js
case 'save-edit':

  //echo 'made it';

  $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
       'edit_article_category' => array(
        'required' => true,
        ),
       'edit_new_post_title' => array(
        'required' => true,
        ),
       'edit_new_post_content' => array(
        'required' => true,
        ),
       'edit_line_type' => array(
        'required' => true,
        ), /*
       'edit_lbtest-select' => array(
        'required' => true,
        ),*/
      ));

     if($validation->passed()){

  $update = $Ambassador->saveEditedArticle();
```

**The function *saveEditedArticle* is found in two files:**

**1) community/profile.php**

```js
function saveEditedArticle()
      {
        event.preventDefault();

        $("#edit_formatted-tags").val($("#edit_tags").tagsinput('items'));
        //alert(tags);
        //var form = $("#article").serialize();

        //alert(tags);
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('setStyle', 'error-input', 'remove');

        $('#new_post_title').removeClass('error-input');
        $('#redactor-uuid-0').removeClass("error-input");

        $.ajax({
          url: './controllers/article.php',
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json',
          crossDomain: 'true',
          data:
                $("#edit_article").serialize()
          ,
          success: function(data){


            if(data == 'validation passed'){

                    $('#edit_validation-error').hide();
                    $('#edit_postbutton').attr('disabled', 'true');
                    $('#edit_submission-success').show();

                      setTimeout(function() {

                          //location.reload();
                          var location = window.location.href;
                          window.location = location;
                      }, 1500);

            } else {
                 for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var field = data[i][0];
                    //$('#'+field).addClass("error-input");
                    if(field=='edit_new_post_title'){
                      $('#edit_new_post_title').addClass("error-input");
                    }
                    if(field=='edit_new_post_content'){
                      $('.redactor-editor').addClass("error-input");
                    }
                    $('#'+field).selectpicker('setStyle', 'error-input');
                    $('#edit_validation-error').show();
              }
            }

          }
        });
    }
```

**2) This is in the file classes/ambassador.php**

```js
 public function saveEditedArticle(){


  $content = Input::get('edit_new_post_content');
  $start = "<img src=\"";
  $end = "\"";

  $image = self::getBetween($content, $start, $end);

  if($image==''){
   $start = "src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/";
   $end = "\"";
   $image = self::getBetween($content, $start, $end);
   if($image!=''){
    $image = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" . $image . "/0.jpg";
   }
   if($image==''){
    $start = "//player.vimeo.com/video/";
    $end = "\"";
    $image = self::getBetween($content, $start, $end);
    if($image!=''){
     $link = 'https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' . $image . '.php';
     $html_returned = unserialize(file_get_contents($link));
     $image = $html_returned[0]['thumbnail_large'];
    }
   } 
  }

  if($image==''){
   $image = 'img/articles/475-33d0f7b0970af583c001559f19c26911.jpg';
  }

  //$content = str_replace('http://', 'https://', Input::get('new_post_content'));

  $slug1 = strtolower(Input::get('edit_article_category'));
  $slug2 = strtolower(Input::get('edit_new_post_title'));

  $slug2 = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/s', '', $slug2);

  
  $slug = $slug1 . '/' . $slug2;
  $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $slug);

  $slug = preg_replace ('/-+/', '-', $slug);

  $article_category = Input::get('edit_article_category');
  $article_title = ucwords(Input::get('edit_new_post_title'));
  $article_content = Input::get('edit_new_post_content');
  $line_category_id = Input::get('edit_line_type');
  //$lb_test_id = Input::get('edit_lbtest-select');
  $tags = Input::get('edit_formatted-tags');
  $article_id = Input::get('article_id');

  $update = $this->_db->update('Article', $article_id,
         array(
           'category'=>$article_category,
           'title'=>$article_title,
           'content'=>$article_content,
           'line_category_id'=>$line_category_id,
           //'lb_test_id'=>$lb_test_id,
           'tags'=>$tags,
           'image_preview'=>$image,
           'slug'=>$slug
         ),
         'id');

 }
```

Comment: 4) A 403 does not necessarily mean that file permissions are the issue. Start by checking the server and application log files to find out what actually caused it.

Comment: @misorude by this you mean the error log files in the same directory as the file that is getting the 403 error?

Comment: No, error logs are usually found in one central place, for the whole site or domain.

Comment: In the error log I got the following:

Comment: In the error log I got the following error: 

[10-Jan-2019 09:16:05 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in community/profile.php on line 898
[10-Jan-2019 09:16:05 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in community/profile.php on line 1083

Comment: Well your code as shown so far doesn’t seem to contain a foreach anywhere. But you know what the error message means, right? So debug the variable in use there, and work your way up from that to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: It says something like its expecting an array.  Before I change the code couldn't this just be because its has the 403 error and can't access the array?

Comment: `I click a button on my website that is supposed to save edits to an article` is it a cross-domain request, meaning the origin site (first.example.com) you click the button on, makes a request to a separate domain (second.example.com)?. Are you using a PHP Framework of some sort? Typically controllers are not accessed directly, but are called by a request handler that loads your app kernel which passes the request to the controller and sends the controller response back to the client.

Comment: @fyrye no it is on the same domain.  As far as a framework it should be MVC.  By app kernal do you mean the initialization file?

Comment: correct, typically an htaccess will have a `mod_rewrite` to `index.php` for all requests that are not a physical file. Which would explain the 403 error when using AJAX on a `/controller` class. MVC is not a Framework, but rather an architectural pattern for programming. A Framework would be a library you use that simplifies development, like jQuery for Javascript. For PHP some popular ones are Symfony, CodeIgniter, or Zend Framework. Others extend base Frameworks to act on their own like Drupal or Laravel.

Comment: `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` would be to allow external domains to make requests to your site via `XMLHTTPRequest` (AJAX). Otherwise known as [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)  You should NOT add it to your htaccess file unless you need an external domain to make requests to your site, which you should specify the domains allowed instead of using `*` or you will be subject to XSS attacks.

Comment: I believe it is from scratch without one of the frameworks above

Comment: The initialization file is one directory up from the directory that has the .htacces file for this controller and is included at the beginning of the file.